# Unix command to remove whitespace in the first few lines

Tags: php, linux, unix

I'm using this unix command(in a php file) to remove a certain string and then remove the whitespace left by that string. Unfortunately in many cases, the files get completely erased.

Is there a workaround?

```
<?php

$dir = "./";

$rmcode = `find $dir -name "*.php"
-type f |xargs sed -i 'somestring' 2>&1`; echo "String removed.<br />\n";

$emptyline = `find $dir -name "*.php"
-type f | xargs sed -i '/./,$!d' 2>&1`; echo "Empty lines removed.<br
/>\n";

?>
```

---

#### Edit

Would this work?

```
$emptyline = `find $dir -name "*.php"
-type f | xargs sed -i '/./,$!d' 2>&1`; echo "Empty lines removed.<br
/>\n";
```

becomes

```
$emptyline = `find $dir -name "*.php"
-type f | xargs sed -i '/\s/,$!d' 2>&1`; echo "Empty lines removed.<br
/>\n";
```

Comment: /./ doesn't match whitespace, it matches everything.

Comment: yes, \s would be correct for whitespaces (and /\s/ with delimiters)

Comment: Are you trying to remove the string from the line that contains it, leaving the rest of the line intact, or are you trying to remove the line that contains the string.  When you say 'remove white space' left by string, do you mean any all blank lines?  Your requirement is not clearly stated, and unclear requirements often lead to unintended 'solutions' to the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the string AND the whitespace all at once:

```
<?php

$dir = "./";

$rmcode = `find $dir -name "*.php" -type f | xargs sed -i 's/somestring\s*//g' 2>&1`; echo "String removed.<br />\n";

?>
```

The `\s` matches whitespace.
The `*` means zero or more times.

---

Updated with working example.

```
fseto@bass:~/src$ echo "test somestring is a test" > testfile
fseto@bass:~/src$ cat testfile
test somestring is a test
fseto@bass:~/src$ sed -i 's/somestring\s*//g' testfile 
fseto@bass:~/src$ cat testfile
test is a test
```

Comment: thanks for the answer...just a quick question..would this remove whitespace from just the line that was removed or also whitespaces after that and within the entire file? thanks!

Comment: i just tried this and it did not seem to delete the string. I tried with the word 'somestring' just as i have it above. In my actual version im using a regex expression instead of somestring. The expression is 's#<?php /\*\*/ eval(base64_decode("aWY.*?>##g' which removes any line of that sort. All the help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to update the question. or post a new question.  In any case, you want to match and remove the whitespace with the string.  Otherwise, you'll have a hard time removing whitespace after the fact.